# why rem will break flex layout even if you don't use it

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
      overflow: scroll;
      min-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
    }
    .chats {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    p {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .box {
      background: blue;
      flex: 1;
    }
    .random {
      padding-top:1rem;
      /* try to un-commnet this rule and the observe the blue box, it will become very small */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chats">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <div class="box">box</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Problem:** if I uncomment the rule `.random`. the layout will break, even though I'm not using it anywhere in the html

**Reproduce:** you need to view this code on mobile (safari/chrome)

**Screenshot without rule `.random`**

[image]

**with rule `.random`**

[image]

Comment: Cab you try changing the rule name ? Maybe it is some kind of special keyword and it is braking something in the rendering engine ?

Comment: I tried that, same thing happens

Comment: Really I cannot explain this. Have you tried perturbating?!?! Like moving the rule up in the css list? Or changing padding to margin to see what happens?

Comment: This is difficult to test but my guess is that this has to do with some invisible character you may have inserted by mistake.

Comment: why is it difficult to test?